# Why is "Up" in "Climb up + noun" a preposition and not an adverb?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs

According to examples in dictionaries, "Up" is a preposition in the following sentences.

1. He climbed up the steps
2. They were climbing up a narrow mountain road.
3. I ran up the stairs and saw Alison lying at the top.

To me, they look like prepositions, but they more look like adverbs.  I don't know how to distinguish them.  Why are they prepositions and not adverbs?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In each case, "up" has an object complement so it can hardly be an adverb. It is a preposition.

Comment: Why do you want to know, and what good will it do you to know that they're one or the other? Labelling words is not what grammar is about. Plus, the labels change all the time and there's a lot of disagreement about them. If your teacher wants to know, tell them anything and go to the next class.

Comment: The labels haven't changed for over 20 years, at least according to what has become the 'standard' work, H&P's CGEL. Aarts, UCL, to name just one, concurs with H&P. In any case, labels are needed to help identify the properties of lexemes and their function in the clause, as well as to draw tree diagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are prepositions because they behave as you would expect a preposition to - they take an optional complement in the form of an NP, do not inflect (up, *uply, *upping, etc.), and, under different circumstances, can appear after a form of ***be*** or as a post-head dependent in a noun phrase.

> He climbed **up**.
>
> He climbed **up** **the steps**.
>
> The wall is **up**.
>
> The wall is **up** **the steps**.
>
> [The way **up**] is blocked.
>
> [The way **up the stairs**] is blocked.

Adverbs cannot appear after ***be*** except in special circumstances such as clefts or when modifying a following verb. They also can not appear as post-head dependents in noun phrases.

> *His response was **violently**.
>
> *[The line **horizontally**] is the one I drew.
>
> He was **violently** attacked.
>
> How he replied was **violently**.

Comment: "On" in "He turned on the light" is an adverb.  Why "Up" in "He climbed up the mountain" is not an adverb, but a preposition?

Comment: @AS "On" is still a preposition in "He turned on the light", for the reasons above, despite what you might read in many dictionaries. They're really not the best place to go for well reasoned grammar classifications.

Comment: @AS DW256 is right. "on" and "up" are prepositions.

Comment: @BillJ Whatever you do, don't turn the light on. A mad dog will turn on its master faster than you can turn on a dime. Titillating images are prone to turning people on.

Comment: First rate answer! Thanks. (You could add that they aren'y modifiable by *very* but are by the specialised adverbs *right* and *straight*, which can't modify adverbs (in standard Englishes).